Stop accordion scrolling the page when clicked. Is this solution good for accessibility?
I'm building an accordion based on this code, as it looked good in terms of accessibility.
I wanted the transition between showing a section and hiding a section of the accordion to be animated and have changed the code slightly. My issue then was that the clicked button would be pushed up and disappear from view as the content grew. I found an explanation and chose a solution, but I'm wondering if this is the best solution accessibility-wise?
I found an explanation for my issue in this post:

The page is keeping the currently active element in view - i.e. the button that you clicked on - so the extra height will appear to move up or down depending on where the button is in relation to the screen.

I'm using the solution provided to keep the page from scrolling, as that seemed best accessibility-wise, but there's another answer that suggests blurring the element. However, wouldn't blurring it affect how a screen reader interacts with the button?
I was wondering if someone could help me clarify what's best for accessibility in this case.
This is my code, for reference:
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    // create an array of all buttons in accordion
    const accordionButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".eqd-accordion__button");
    
    accordionButtons.forEach(button => {
        const contentId = button.getAttribute("aria-controls");
        const content = document.getElementById(contentId);
        const contentHeight = document.getElementById(contentId + "-height").offsetHeight;
        // check if an accordion section is expanded
        const isExpanded = button.getAttribute("aria-expanded") === "true";

        if(isExpanded) {
            // set height of visible section
            content.style.visibility = "visible";
            content.style.height = contentHeight + "px";
        } else {
            // Collapse accordions that have aria-expanded false attr
            const contentToHide = document.getElementById(button.getAttribute("aria-controls"));

            if (contentToHide) {
                contentToHide.style.height = "0";
                contentToHide.style.visibility = "hidden";
            }
        }

        // add an onclick event to each button
        button.addEventListener("click", function() {
            // on click
            // check if an accordion section is expanded
            const isExpanded = button.getAttribute("aria-expanded") === "true";
        
            // Collapse ALL accordions
            accordionButtons.forEach(btn => {
                // click event listener tracks which button I've clicked & I can get the corresponding content via ID by passing my aria-controls attribute
                const contentToHide = document.getElementById(btn.getAttribute("aria-controls"));
                btn.setAttribute("aria-expanded", "false");
                if (contentToHide) {
                    contentToHide.style.height = "0";
                    contentToHide.style.visibility = "hidden";
                }
            });
        
            // If the clicked accordion was not expanded, expand it
            if (!isExpanded) {
                button.setAttribute("aria-expanded", "true");
                content.style.visibility = "visible";
                content.style.height = contentHeight + "px";
                const pagePosBeforeExpand = window.scrollY;
                window.scrollTo({ top: pagePosBeforeExpand });
            }
        });
    });
});

This is the live example: https://www.becky-matthews.com/content-writing/

If the heading you're clicking is at the bottom of the viewport, a user might not notice that the accordion even opened, since is cut-out by the overflow. On your site something terrible happens instead, the page arguably seems like scrolling on a random position within the content. I'd suggest to: if there's enough space below the header to see additional content appear, keep it still, otherwise scroll just enough to anchor the heading to the top of the viewport (with animation).

Try always to provide a [mre] of your problem. External links are eventually fine, but might go dead sooner or later, making your question incomplete for future readers.

I think you can just use <details> and remove all the js code

@RokoC.Buljan Thank you for pointing out those issues! Those are exactly the things that I'm trying to solve... Unfortunately, even more random scrolling was happening when I tried anchoring the heading to the top of the viewport. I think this might have been happening, because the button was automatically being scrolled to be kept in view and the content was growing a lot. I'll look more into MRE, as well!

@LãNgọcHải That's a good shout, thank you! I've somehow not heard of this tag before, but it sounds like it might be just what I need.
